# Confusion with VirtualBox forwarding and ufw rules

Tags: debian, virtualbox, ufw

Got a requirement to run some old software running on an old Linux box using VirtualBox, but want to lock it down so that only very specific ports can be accessed from very specific IP addresses.

The thing is that VirtualBox's NAT routing seems to bypass the IPTables rules set up by ufw.

VBoxManage shows:

NIC 1: MAC: XXXXXXXX, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: Am79C973, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = xyz, protocol = tcp, host ip = X.X.X.108, host port = 1234, guest ip = , guest port = 1234

If I try to connect from some random Internet address to X.X.X.108:1234 it works, but I'm trying to work out how to stop it working, but only allow from trusted IP addresses.

ufw insert 1 deny 1234

Doesn't work

ufw route insert 1 deny 1234

Doesn't work

What am I missing?!